# App se cierra creo que es por error en código de validación

Tags: android-studio, validación

Uso Android Studio 3, luego de ver varios tutoriales, hice una app con validación para dos formularios Cliente y TipoTransacción. No estoy seguro si uso la expresión regular adecuada para texto y espacio. En fin, si la validación es correcta, se debería seguir a otra activity donde se vea el mensaje Cliente validado o Tipo transacción validada según corresponda. La app se cierra al ejecutarla y antes funcionaba, lo que me muestra que hay un error en mi código, pero soy nuevo en esto, le agradezco mucho a alguien con experiencia que pueda decirme.

ActivityMain

```
package com.example.jhon.cesde5;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.sax.StartElementListener;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextInputLayout impEditDescripcion, impEditDocIdent, impEditPassword, impTextNombre, impTextApellido, impTextDireccion;
    TextInputLayout impTextTelefono, impEditFechaIngreso, impTextEstado;
    EditText editTextDescripcion, editDocIdent, editPassword, textNombre, textApellido, textDireccion, textTelefono,
    textEstado, editFechaIngreso;
    Button butIngresar, butIngresarCliente;
    boolean vDocIdent=false, vNombre=false, vApellido=false, vFechaIngreso=false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        impEditDescripcion=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.impEditDescripcion);
        impEditDocIdent=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.impEditDocIdent);
        impEditPassword=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.impEditPassword);
        impTextNombre=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.impTextNombre);
        impTextApellido=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.impTextApellido);
        impTextDireccion=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.impTextDireccion);
        impTextTelefono=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.impTextTelefono);
        impEditFechaIngreso=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.impEditFechaIngreso);
        impTextEstado=(TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.impTextEstado);

        editTextDescripcion=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextDescripcion);
        editDocIdent=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editDocIdent);
        editPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        textNombre=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textNombre);
        textApellido=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textApellido);
        textDireccion=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textDireccion);
        textTelefono=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textTelefono);
        textEstado=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textEstado);
        editFechaIngreso=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editFechaIngreso);

        butIngresar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.butIngresar);
        butIngresarCliente=(Button) findViewById(R.id.butIngresarCliente);

        butIngresarCliente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z\\s]");

                if(p.matcher(textNombre.getText().toString()).matches()==false){
                    impTextNombre.setError("Debe ingresar sólo letras");
                    vNombre=false;
                }else{
                    vNombre=true;
                    impTextNombre.setError(null);
                }

                if(p.matcher(textApellido.getText().toString()).matches()==false){
                    impTextApellido.setError("Debe ingresar sólo letras");
                    vApellido=false;
                }else{
                    vApellido=true;
                    impTextApellido.setError(null);
                }

                Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]");

                if(p2.matcher(editDocIdent.getText().toString()).matches()==false){
                    impEditDocIdent.setError("Debe ingresar sólo números y máximo 7");
                    vDocIdent=false;
                }else{
                    vDocIdent=true;
                    impEditDocIdent.setError(null);
                }


                if(vNombre==true && vApellido==true && vDocIdent==true){
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ClienteValidadoClase.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });


        butIngresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String descripcion = editTextDescripcion.getText().toString();
                if(descripcion.length()>0){
                    Intent i2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TipoTransaccionValidada.class);
                    startActivity(i2);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No puede estar vacío", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void ejecutar_cliente_activity(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ClienteClase.class);

        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void ejecutar_tipo_transaccion(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TipoTransaccionClase.class);

        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void Salir(View view){
        finish();
    }    


}
```

logcat

```
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setSocketWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@13280021@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):13)
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: setsockopt failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
09-19 04:31:39.419 2241-7904/? W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setSocketWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@13280021@13.2.80 (040408-211705629):13)
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: setsockopt failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)

java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:505)
    at android.os.FileBridge$FileBridgeOutputStream.writeCommandAndBlock(FileBridge.java:165)
    at android.os.FileBridge$FileBridgeOutputStream.close(FileBridge.java:152)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:67)
    at com.google.common.io.i.a(SourceFile:2)
    at com.google.android.finsky.apkprocessor.l.a(SourceFile:34)
    at com.google.android.finsky.apkprocessor.l.doInBackground(SourceFile:81)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at com.google.android.finsky.utils.bn.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
    at libcore.io.Posix.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.Posix.write(Posix.java:271)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:313)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:500)
    at android.os.FileBridge$FileBridgeOutputStream.writeCommandAndBlock(FileBridge.java:165) 
    at android.os.FileBridge$FileBridgeOutputStream.close(FileBridge.java:152) 
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:67) 
    at com.google.common.io.i.a(SourceFile:2) 
    at com.google.android.finsky.apkprocessor.l.a(SourceFile:34) 
    at com.google.android.finsky.apkprocessor.l.doInBackground(SourceFile:81) 
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:307) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
    at com.google.android.finsky.utils.bn.run(Unknown Source) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jhon.cesde5"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="ClienteClase"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".TipoTransaccionClase"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".ClienteValidadoClase"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".TipoTransaccionValidada"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes ver lo que pone en la ventana Logcat? Ahí suelen aparecer los errores de ejecución

Comment: 07:36 AM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

07:36 AM Gradle build finished in 14s 922ms

Comment: Eso no es un error. Intenta buscar donde ponga algo de una exception o, directamente, pon todo lo que aparezca en logcat aquí

Comment: 2241-12054/? E/NetworkScheduler: Invalid component specified.  904-1521/? E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 102   2241-10661/? E/NetworkScheduler: Invalid component specified.   904-2040/? E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 102     2241-12054/? E/NetworkScheduler: Invalid component specified.

Comment: 09-18 07:46:39.507 14514-14564/? E/YouTube: Failed delayed event dispatch, no dispatchers.
09-18 07:46:39.524 452-452/? E/Thermal-daemon: [Thermal_Hw] temperature_valid, battery : temperature is invalid, invalid temperatrue is 31

Comment: Lo siento pero sigo sin ver dónde se produce el error en tu código

Comment: Puse el logcat arriba para que se vea mejor. De ahí se ve:  unable to get realpath for the library   y   Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83325/discussion-between-javi-molla-and-jhon-hernandez).

Comment: @JhonHernández el mensaje del LogCat que agregas en realidad es del sistema operativo, debes buscar el de error que indique "Caused by", aplica el filtro "Show only selected application".

Comment: Usé el filtro que dices @Jorgesys